# Real time dashboard with aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I am building real-time dashboard using aws services, currently my application using MySQL database(RDS), which service and how would be designed real-time dashboard using Amazon web service, currently my approach is to use kinesis with redshift and connect my application via JDBC connector or use kinesis with s3 and use Athena to show real-time aggregators.

please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: help with what exactly?

Comment: Hi @JonScott thanks for the reply, I am trying to build real-time dashboard, can you suggest which aws service would be best for that.

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap, your question is not clear. What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ohh sorry, @JohnRotenstein actually I am looking for solution, mean what would be the best solution for above scenario and I read blog and my question comes under suggestions, I am sorry if I made any mistake

Comment: you say " currently my approach is to use kinesis with redshift and connect my application via JDBC connector or use kinesis with s3 and use Athena to show real-time aggregators". what is wrong with that ? what have you tried? share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Although the [Amazon Kinesis Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html) mention that Kinesis streams can be used to send updates to dashboards, Kinesis has no native mechanism to do this alone. For some very good security reasons it's unwise to allow clients (i.e. from a webpage you serve) to access backend services like Kinesis directly.

Instead, you'll want to set up your application layer (Java, in this case) to listen to the Kinesis streams and expose any relevant events to your client, storing any changes you need to keep track of in your database (RDS, in this case). For a real-time dashboard I'd recommend using something like WebSockets to send events in real time to your webpage from your server, as they're widely supported and easy to use. Heres a [tutorial](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/) on how to implement WebSockets on GlassFish